# Automatic Memoization of Complex Data Types in OCaml via Enumeration?

Tags: ocaml, memoization

I am writing an implementation of a mathematically described algorithm into OCaml. I am trying to keep the implementation clean and close to the paper, and use only well defined techniques like memorization to improve performance.

Unfortunately, while memoization works quite well on integers, it can still be O(n) for large or complex data types. It is possible to get O(1) performance by enumerating the data types before memoization. 
For example, we see in the example below that `memo len` would still be O(n), but `DroidMemoized.len` would be O(1) and that `DroidMemoized` is a drop in replacement for `Droid`.

However, is it possible to create `DroidMemoized` from `Droid`automatically? For example, is there a Module EnumMemo such that we can write `let DroidMemoized = EnumMemo.Make(Droid)`?

```
module Droid = struct
        type t = string
        let  empty = ""
        let  beep x = x ^ " notdroids"
        let  boop x = x ^ " lookingfor"
        let  len x = String.length x
end

let memo f =
  let m = Hashtbl.create 9 in
    fun x ->
      try Hashtbl.find m x
      with Not_found ->
        let y = f x in
          Hashtbl.add m x y; y

module DroidMemoized = struct
        (* Boilerplate *)
        let to_id_h   : (Droid.t, int) Hashtbl.t = Hashtbl.create 9
        let from_id_h : (int, Droid.t) Hashtbl.t = Hashtbl.create 9 (*or use array*)
        let size = ref 0
        let from_id i = (Hashtbl.find from_id_h i)
        let to_id (x :Droid.t) : int = 
                if      Hashtbl.mem  to_id_h x 
                then    Hashtbl.find to_id_h x
                else    (size := (!size)+1;
                        Hashtbl.add  to_id_h   x (!size);
                        Hashtbl.add  from_id_h (!size) x;
                        !size)
        (* Function wrappers *)
        let empty = to_id Droid.empty
        let beep = memo ( fun x -> to_id (Droid.beep (from_id x)) )
        let boop = memo ( fun x -> to_id (Droid.boop (from_id x)) )
        let len  = memo ( fun x ->       (Droid.len  (from_id x)) )
end
```

Comment: Why `~O(log n)?` Isn't Hashtbl in `O(1)`?

Comment: Well, O(1) average case with a good hash function, and O(n) worst case, we can get O(log n) worst case with a red black tree. I'll just change to O(1) since these details are not too relevant to the question.

Answer (score 0):

The boiler plate is easy to generate for Functors, but the best I can do for function wrappers is use an external utility to parse the OCaml signatures, e.g.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
@signature=`ocaml < droid.ml`;
our $t;
foreach(@signature) {
   if (/type t = (\w+)/  ){
      $t=$1;
   } elsif (/val (\w+) : (\w+)$/){
      print "let $1 = " .
         ( ($2 eq $t) ? " to_id " : "") .
         "( Droid.$1 )\n";
   } elsif (/val (\w+) : (\w+) -> (\w+)$/){
      print "let $1 = " .
         ( ($3 eq "unit") ? "(" : "memo (") . 
         " fun x -> " .
         ( ($3 eq $t) ? "to_id (" : "(") .
         ( ($2 eq $t) ? " from_id" : "") .
         " (Droid.$1 x))\n";
   }
}
```

I have brushed this up into a Perl script to memoize modules: https://github.com/gmatht/joshell/blob/master/scripts/memoize.pl

Comment: A better answer would give a clean Ocaml way of doing this, or an "it can't be done" by someone with more experience in OCaml; I won't accept my own answer.